# exact instructions for sending an SMS via a wireless modem

Tags: sms

What are the step-by-step and exact instructions for getting one of the following to send an SMS via a Huawei E398 or similar wireless modem?  This unit is 4G wireless with USB from the modem to the computer.

`Wammu/Gammu` or

`ixconn` or

`vodafone-mobile-connect-card-driver-for-linux` or

`SMSlib`

Please include all command lines necessary to research the parameter settings for the application.  Examples: `lsusb` and `ls /dev` and what to look for.

Note that the other three are apps but `SMSlib` is a Java API.  You can assume that Java skills are available so that the only relevant problem is parameterization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Disconnect ubuntu from the Huawei E398 modem.  This can be done from the task bar where `Enable Mobile Broadband` can be unchecked.
2. Using `Wammu` and `Gammu`, run from the `Wammu` menu `Phone Wizard` and select the `Manual Configuration` method.  Enter the port such as `/dev/ttyUSB0` and connection type `at115200`.
3. After the wizard discovers the modem, enter a name for the configuration.  `HuaweiE398` was fine for me.
4. From the menu select `Phone, Connect`.
5. From the menu select `Create, Message` and put in the phone number and text content.  Select the `Send Message` checkbox and send it.  You can also retrieve messages as follows: from the menu select `Retrieve, Messages`.